# Apple Studio Display with Lenovo P1 running Windows 10

Tags: display, thunderbolt

I have a Lenovo P1 (Gen 2) running Windows 10, and I am trying to get it to work with my new Apple Studio Display. The laptop has 2 x Thunderbolt 3 ports, and I have tried plugging in the display (using the cable that came with the display) into both of these ports. When I do this, the laptop seems to recognise the display, i.e., it shows up in my displays (see pic), and the speakers and microphone connect. Sound comes out of the speakers, and I think the microphone works, however, there is no picture.

Any thoughts on how I can get the display to work as expected?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cable Apple provides does not work with the Lenovos over thunderbolt 3. Get another cable that supports power delivery.

Comment: When sir antihero cable - do you mean another Thunderbolt cable?